# Multiples within interval

Tags: algorithm

Given a number **n** and some interval (**L : R**), how can I count the multiples of **n** within this interval?

If I do (R-L+1)/n, it won't give me right answer, cos for example, within 3 and 5, there are one multiple of 4, but (5-3+1)/4 = 0, within 4 and 8, there are 2 multiples of 4, but (8-4+1)/4 = 1.

I tried this but it wont work too (fail in *div(4,4,13) = 2* )

```
int div(int n, int l, int r){
    let mod = n - l % n;
    let first = mod == n? l : l + mod;
    return first > r? 0 : (r-first+1)/n + 1;
}
```

the point is: I don't wanna check a thousand things, I guess there's some fast way to do it.

Comment: Are L,n,R non-negative?

Comment: Assume L>=0 - it's intuitive

Comment: question is how many multiples of n are there between L and R, noth positive integers

Comment: I was thinking about count multiples until L, than until R and subtract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't

```
R/n - (L-1)/n
```

work assuming integer divisions here? Since `R/n` is the number of multiples of n <= R, and `(L-1)/n` the number of multiples of n < L, the difference is what you want.

Comment: @downvoter - a counter example will be nice. Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your answer anyway so I could change my missdownvote into upvote?

Comment: @xenteros: Sure, anything for the reps. Thanks!

Comment: funny that as this is an integer division, you can't optimize the operation to (R - L + 1)/n  even that it means the same, cos it will "forget" values that are not forgotten if you make the division in separate (eg: 3 and 5)